# Icon not show in google search result + description (react js)

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have issue regarding my favicon not appearing in google search result + some time my description not show insteads it show you need to enable javascript to run this app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I fixed this problem by generate the favicons on this website https://realfavicongenerator.net/ and placed all the code in index.html file that this website generate for me